# unexpected behaviour in using Go range syntax

Tags: go, struct, range

Probably just because I'm new to Go, but using the range syntax over arrays of structs doesn't behave as I'd expect. I'm assuming the array item gets copied to the range index, but the copy isn't a deep copy ... so the following is a little weird. Is this behaviour documented somewhere

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Inner struct {
        x, y int
}
type Attr struct {
        a      int
        inside []Inner
}

var item = []Attr{
        {a: 1, inside: []Inner{{2, 3}, {3, 4}}},
        {a: 2, inside: []Inner{{3, 4}, {1, 2}}},
}

func main() {
        fmt.Println(item) 
        for _,i := range item {
                // A: The following has no impact on item[].a
                i.a = 111
                // B: But this does ... why?
                i.inside[0].x = 111
        }
        fmt.Println(item) 
        for j,_  := range item {
                item[j].a = 333
                item[j].inside[0].x = 333
        }
        fmt.Println(item)
}
```

Comment: Slices are also passed by values, but their value is a _descriptor_ that refers to original slice. This is documented [here](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro): `A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).`

Answer (score 0):

In the loop `for _, i := range item`, each `i` is a copy of the corresponding slice element. Suppose, you write:

```
i := item[0]
i.a = 111
```

this does not change the original element of the slice, but only its copy. However in:

```
i.inside[0].x = 111
```

`inside` is a slice, i.e. only a thin wrapper referring to the underlying array, which is not copied on assignment. So with `i.inside` you deal with the same slice as `items[0].inside`.

[More about slices internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro).